# Display file contents in a popup window upon pressing a key?

Tags: neovim, vim8, popup-menu

I am having a text file where I have a cheat sheet of commands I learned.
When pressing some key ,it should be displayed in popup window. In Kakoune editor they display a help using Alt+i , like that I want to show my cheatsheet in popup windows.

As i am learning VIM recently , this sheet might be helpful in reminding the commands.
How to do it via vimrc? My cheatsheet is copied in `~/.vim_cheatsheet`. I am using Vim 8.2

Comment: Please, be specific, if  the question is about Vim or Neovim. These two are very different programs, especially concerning popup window implementation.

Comment: @Matt Oh.. That difference also there . I did not think that. So some plugin which can do show a help file in popup window this can be achievable. isn't it ?

Comment: I may be very late but you may try this https://github.com/ubaldot/helpme-vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar before. I was learning Vim's fold commands. I just
stuffed my cheat sheet in a string that separated each line with a comma...

```
let g:foldcmds = split("zf  (Plus a motion) Operator to create a fold.,zF   Create a fold for [count] lines.  Works like zf.,zd Delete one fold at the cursor.,zD   Delete folds recursively at the cursor.,zE  Eliminate all folds in the window.,zo   Open one fold under the cursor.,",',')
```

(That's an abbreviated version.)

Alternatively, read the cheatsheet from a file:

```
let g:foldcmds = readfile('/path/to/file')
```

Each line in the file will get a line in the popup.

You'd call it like this *for example*...

```
:call popup_create(g:foldcmds, #{ title: ' Fold Commands  ', 
    padding: [0,1,0,1], border: [], filter: 'popup_filter_yesno', close: 'click' })
```

Then I stuck it in a mapping...

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>z :call popup_create(g:foldcmds, #{ title: ' Fold Commands  ', 
    padding: [0,1,0,1], border: [], filter: 'popup_filter_yesno' })<CR>
```

Result:

[image]

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> to exit.

Comment: I am not good at vimscript. Can I show my file contents line by line in popup window?

Comment: It displays error as below Error detected while processing /root/.vimrc:
line    1:
E484: Can't open file ~/vimcheatsheet
line    3:
E723: Missing end of Dictionary '}':
E116: Invalid arguments for function popup_create
line    4:
E492: Not an editor command:             padding: [0,1,0,1], border: [], filter: 'popup_filter_yesno', close: 'click' })

Comment: Put popup/mapping commands on a single line. They're only split up above for readabililty.

Comment: It still says E484: Can't open file ~/vimcheatsheet . I even did chmod 777 to that file

Comment: To use `~` you may have to do `readfile(expand('~/filename'))`. (Or just use full path like I said.)